# While using axios to POST data in mongodb , I'm only getting ObjectId and no other data is posted

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, crud, mern

I'm building a simple crud applicaton using MERN stack
Below is the code for adding user details in db

```
import React , {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const initialValue = {
  name: '',
  username: '',
  email: '',
  phone: ''
}

const AddUser = () => {
// hooks
const [user, setUser] = useState(initialValue);
const { name, username, email, phone } = user; 

let navigate = useNavigate();
const onValueChange = (e) => {
    setUser({...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}

// ADD USER
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}

const addUser = async (user) => {
  return await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/add", user , config);
}
const addUserDetails = async() => {
    await addUser(user);
    navigate('/all');
}

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Add Details</h1>
      <form className="form">
      <input onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)} placeholer="Add Name"name='name' value={name} id="my-input" />
      <input onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)} placeholer="Add Username"name='username' value={username} id="my-input" />
      <input onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)} placeholer="Add Email"name='email' value={email} id="my-input" />
      <input onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)} placeholer="Add Phone"name='phone' value={phone} id="my-input" />
      <button type="submit" onClick={() => addUserDetails()}>Add</button>
      </form>
    
    </div>
  )
}

export default AddUser
```

Below is the screenshot of mongodb
[image: only object_id is posted]

Below is Route.js

```
    const router = require('express').Router();
    const User = require('../model/todoItems.js');
    
    // Coming from model
    
    // POST DATA
    router.post('/add',async (req,res) =>{
    
    try { 
      const newUser = new User({user: req.body.user});
    
      // saving in db
      await newUser.save();
      res.status(201).json(newUser);
      
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(409).json({ message: error.message});     
    }
    }
    );
    
    module.exports = router;
```

Below is the model

```
const mongoose = require( 'mongoose');


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user:{
    name: String,
    username: String,
    email: String,
    phone: Number
  }
    
});

module.exports= mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

{_id:ObjectId(641548f49338e07c498bf231),__v:0}
this is what I'm getting
database is connected successfully.
I want all the details to be posted what should I do ?

Comment: Can you add code for node api where you add user?

Comment: Are you sure tou import the right model here? `const User = require('../model/todoItems.js');` , maybe you meant user.js? Also can you add `console.log(req.body)` in the add method and say what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code. I guess the problem will resolve when you correct them.

1-) Check you import the right model in your route.js. Because it is todoItem.js. I guess it must be something related with user.

```
 const User = require('../model/todoItems.js');
```

2-) In mongoose model, there is no need to use user as the parent. Simply remove it so that it looks like:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    username: String,
    email: String,
    phone: Number
});
```

3-) In route.js, change the const newUser line like this:

```
const newUser = new User(req.body);
```

4-) Be sure you get the correct req.body using console.log

```
console.log("req.body: ", req.body);
const newUser = new User(req.body);
```